# How to create a line with a select using a Cross Join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table, and I want to do a select in the fields and create a new line with this select, like the example:

```
campo1  campo2 campo3
  1        2      3
```

Resultset:

```
campo1  campo2 campo3
   1       2      3
   2       3      3
```

I make a code using a union and works but I want use a CROSS JOIN, and I dont know how

```
SELECT CAMPO1, CAMPO2, CAMPO3 FROM TABELA
UNION
SELECT CAMPO1 + 1, CAMPO2 +1, CAMPO3 FROM TABELA
```

Comment: Why didn't what you have work?

Comment: It works, but I don't know if it's the most efficient way.

Comment: That's not what you asked. A `UNION` removes duplicates which requires an expensive sort. `UNION ALL` doesn't eliminate duplicates. Beyond that, the execution plan will tell you how efficient this is. Perhaps the query optimizer is smart enough to generate the results in a single scan, perhaps not. If it does, there's no reason to try a JOIN. If it *doesn't*, you can use a CROSS JOIN with a table containing the values to add to the first 2 columns, ie `(0,0),(1,1)`

Comment: I think, I dont explain very well, but that is what I want, make a CROSS JOIN using (0,0), (1,1), but I dont know haw

Comment: Please explain why you want to make a `CROSS JOIN`, because that serves a complete other purpose then doing a `UNION` which give the correct resultset.

Comment: Because I have several columns where I will have to change each one of them in several different ways, making it necessary to have several unions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a cross join you can use a `values` construct:

```
select t.campo1+v, t.campo2+v, t.campo3
from (
  values(0),(1) 
)x(v)
cross join t
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can also use `APPLY`**

```sql
SELECT
  v.campo1,
  v.campo2,
  t.campo3
FROM t
CROSS APPLY (VALUES
    (t.campo1,     t.campo2),
    (t.campo1 + 1, t.campo2 + 1) 
) v(campo1, campo2);
```